# DOMParser security risks when extracting urls and titles

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I need to parse an HTML string from an untrusted source, in order to extract the hyperlink titles and urls.

I assume DOMParser will not execute any javascript, and not make any network requests (e.g. loading the src of any img tags)?

I will reject any urls that don't start with http:// or https://

I will also ensure that I never write any link titles into the page using `.innerHTML`, and will always use `a.textContent = ...` to set the link titles.

Are there any other security considerations I should be aware of? Is DOMParser fully sandboxed?

```js
const html = `<h1><a href="https://www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a></h1>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
const link = doc.querySelector('a');
console.log(`${link.textContent} ${link.href}`);
```

Comment: I believe your assumption is correct -- it just parses, it doesn't execute anything.